# How to reset QLineEdit text by pressing Escape key?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm working on a Qt4 project. I have a `QLineEdit` and I want to re-use behavior that I see when I click the Escape key inside the `QLineEdit`, but I'm not sure how.

When I press the escape key, I get the field to reset to the value that it was before I started editing. This is useful to me and I want this behavior on-hand.

Ideally, I would like a signal I can fire off that triggers the `QLineEdit` to reset to the value it was before. I would prefer not to try and fake an escape key event. I can cache the old value of the line edit, but this seems more work if the behavior already exists when I click escape. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make QLineEdit widget to respond on Escape key by setting
>   the text programmatically?

Either by overriding `QWidget::event` virtual function with the child of `QLineEdit` or a bit more "local", like installing the event filter:

```
    class MyLineEditEventFilter : public QObject
    {
    public:
        explicit MyLineEditEventFilter(QLineEdit *parent) : QObject(parent)
        {}

        bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
        {
            switch (e->type())
            {
                case QEvent::KeyPress:
                {
                    QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e);
                    if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
                    {
                        // or set the other text from the variable
                        reinterpret_cast<QLineEdit *>(parent())->setText("Escape!");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            // standard event processing
            return QObject::eventFilter(obj, e);
        }
    };
```

And the caller is like that:

```
m_pLineEditSearch = new QLineEdit;
auto* pLineEditEvtFilter = new MyLineEditEventFilter(m_pLineEditSearch);
m_pLineEditSearch->installEventFilter(pLineEditEvtFilter);
```

For getting the previous text to reset with Escape pressed you may use different methods but you need to obtain the pointer to the object holding the string somehow. That is hard to answer without seeing your code.

Comment: This is clear to me. I am subclassing the QLineEdit so it makes sense to override the event behavior.

I guess I was just hoping that I could get a signal or a method on this object that reproduces that behavior, since it already exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `QDataWidgetMapper` and map your `QLineEdit` to its model. The Esc key behavior you're mentioning is already built-in there. You can also take advantage of the other functionalities that `QDataWidgetMapper` provides.

Here's how you would use it:

```
//Your model can have multiple rows and columns, let's assume it's just one
//QLineEdit, that will mean one row and one column
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(1,1,this);
QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem("QLineEdit initial value");
QLineEdit* myLineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
QDataWidgetMapper* dataWidgetMapper = new QDataWidgetMapper(this);
dataWidgetMapper->setModel(model);
dataWidgetMapper->addMapping(myLineEdit, 0);
dataWidgetMapper->toFirst();
```

Hope this helps.

`UPDATE:`

There have been some valid concerns raised in the comments under my section about some of the pitfalls of `QDataWidgetMapper,` namely the fact that it not only responds to Escape key but also other keys like Enter/Return. So what happens is that after calling `QDataWidgetMapper::addMapping(QWidget*, int)` an event filter will be installed on your widget, which will consume Escape and Enter/Return keys. If you are still interested in finding out whether Enter or Escape have been pressed, you can add one more event filter right after that where you can check for other keys pressed. I have tried it and it works.

Comment: QDataWidgetMapper not only listens to the escape key but also other keys, do you think your answer is adequate?

Comment: @eyllanesc, you're right, it does. I thought if someone wants a specific behavior for the Escape key that QDataWidgetMapper provides, they also might be interested in its other capabilities too...

Comment: A quality response should respond to the OP, in your case that class is oversized, do not you think? The answers do not serve to promote other classes.

Comment: I think we had already discussed the number of lines, the number of lines is irrelevant in the answer, your function will be launched with other keys, do not you think that will generate problems?

Comment: Do you expect a question to be answered after 2 years? The asker is probably not active.

Comment: That's why he asks about the inconveniences, what other keys would also be detected?

Comment: Would the enter and return keys also be detected?

Comment: Yes, they will be... but he may ignore those if he wants to, because upon Enter/Return, things are getting saved in the model.

Comment: mmm, and if before that action you want to implement a logic that has no memory, how will you restore the state before the change?

Comment: QDataWidgetMapper::setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper::ManualSubmit) and then QDataWidgetMapper::revert()...

Comment: I do not talk about it, but let's say that when you press escape you have to randomly modify a list of elements, how would you reverse that event?

Comment: @eyllanesc, I don't know, enlighten me:)

Comment: is that it is not possible, with your method you can detect other keys, and the asker only indicates that you want to detect the escape key

Comment: @eyllanesc, you mean if we use QDataWidgetMapper we have no way of knowing if an Escape key was pressed at all?

Comment: How do you differentiate that the escape key was pressed, and not the enter or return key?

Comment: @eyllanesc, maybe there is a signal that is being emitted? I don't know. Will appreciate if you tell me.

Comment: is that it is not possible to differentiate if the key that was pressed was enter, escape, return, so I tell you that your answer is not correct. The question is clear, just want to detect the escape key, not other keys.

Comment: Do not think that adding other filters is more work than just a filter as proposed in the other solution, your solution: 1 QDataWidgetMapper + eventFilters, the other solution: 1 eventFilter ;)

Comment: @eyllanesc, well I was hoping the OP would not care about the other key strokes, but if he does then he should not resort to my solution:)

Comment: I go to the direct question, so I asked you to indicate the pros and cons of your solution, and for me it generates more problems than solutions. I think that's where the discussion ended, goodbye. ;)